# Where Does Helm Install Charts Locally

Tags: docker, docker-compose, kubernetes-helm

I am new Helm. Where does helm install charts locally and can I change this location?
I need to set the location of the installed charts to a hosted volume in Docker.

Comment: whats your tried ? please edit your question

Comment: It's unclear what you want to accomplish. Please elaborate.

Comment: I'm not following this question.  Helm installs charts using the Kubernetes API, not "locally", and Docker isn't usually directly involved in this process at all.  Can you clarify what you're attempting, what code you've written, and what problem you're running into?

Comment: For example if I type: `helm pull stable/mediawiki`. Where does that get stored locally?

Answer (score -1):

If you are fetching a remote helm chart with `pull` or `fetch` command, It will write the chart in a current directory.

You can use --destination/-d  to specify the location to write the chart.

For example:

```sh
$ helm pull stable/nginx-lego
$ ls
nginx-lego-0.3.1.tgz


$ helm pull stable/nginx-lego -d somedir
```

Comment: Thanks. I seen it using your example.